# Can you do rag doll physics with Sprite Kit?

Tags: sprite-kit, ragdoll

Is it possible to do rag doll physics in Sprite Kit?

I haven't been able to find anything online about this. I think it would be possible since Sprite Kit has the needed joints. Has anyone done something similar? I'm going to fool around with it and see if I can't make one. If I succeed I will post the code. But, in the meantime if someone has already done it, it would be great to not have to charter this territory alone!

Comment: These article/tutorials might help http://www.raywenderlich.com/59535/integrating-spine-spritekit-tutorial
http://www.raywenderlich.com/54511/2d-skeletal-animation-with-spine-tutorial Might be a decent starting place.

Comment: Have you found anything else out about this? I'm turning up nothing on an initial search.

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything on this and actually gave up on the idea after failing. It seems to me that when making joints between physics bodies in order to have them be stable and not fall apart you must abide by certain guidelines (e.g. one body has greater mass than others if two joints are attached to it, and also joints connect bodies with a certain amount of overlap). Since this isn't really documented, and the rag doll i made kept falling apart under lots of force i gave up. I bet this year at the WWDC they will make adjustments to spritekits physics.